# How to filter out entries from List[Map[String,String]]?

Tags: scala

I want to filter **out** those entries that have `operation_id` equal to `"0"`.

```
val operations_seen_qty = parsed.flatMap(_.lift("operation_id")).toSet.size.toString
```

`parsed` is `List[Map[String,String]]`.

How can I do it?

This is my draft, but I think that I am in contrast selecting only those entries that have `operation_id` equal to 0:

`val operations_seen_qty = parsed.flatMap(_.lift("operation_id")).filter(p=>p.equals("0")).toSet.size.toString`

The final objective is to count the number of unique `operation_id` values that are not equal to `"0"`.

Comment: The map key is a `List[String]`? That seems a little odd. Could you add a little more background to this question, more about how you'd got to a `Map[List[String], String]`, perhaps there's an alternative data structure that would fit this better.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: Sorry, it's `List[Map[String,String]]`. I corrected this typo error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you only want to retain those entries whose entry id is NOT equal to "0". In this case, the function in the filter should be `p=>!p.equals("0")` or `p=>p!="0"`.

Filter will retain the entries fulfill the predicate. What you did is exactly the opposite.

Comment: Is it the same as `p=>p!="0"`?

Comment: @Dinosaurius yes, I think so.

Comment: In my case `parsed` is `List[Map[String,String]]`. Will it work in this case?

Comment: @Dinosaurius sorry, I didn't see your edit of the question. Actually you are on the right track, just modify the logic inside the `filter` to the one in my answer will be OK.